# Dual booting Kali Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, kali-linux

I need to dual boot my pc. Kali &  Windows. I have Windows installed. I just created a 50 GB partition for the Linux install and when I get to the partitioning section of the Kali installation, it does not display my Windows partition. It instead displays my whole hard disk as unpartioned space. Anyone know why? Or perhaps something is wrong with my hard disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own :

When Windows converts drive to MBR from gpt it does not do it correctly. It leaves the backup gpt partition table. Then Linux tools see MBR and backup gpt and do not know what you have or want and just assume you want to erase entire drive to make it consistent. So you need to remove the GPT entreis that were left/didn't get converted

You can use Fixparts to remove the stray GPT entries. There's a guide here >> http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/

Fixparts is the easiest option but if it does not work:

Converting to or from GPT
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html